# AttributeError: 'FITSFigure' object has no attribute 'set_tick_labels_font'

Tags: python, subplot, aplpy

I am a beginner in programming. I am trying to produce two plots using APLpy and subplot and simple code.

The code is as following:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')

import aplpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl

fig = mpl.figure(figsize=(15, 7))

f1 = aplpy.FITSFigure('snr.5500-drop.fits', figure=fig, subplot=[0.1,0.1,0.35,0.8])
f1.set_tick_labels_font(size='x-small')
f1.set_axis_labels_font(size='small')
f1.show_grayscale()

f2 = aplpy.FITSFigure('snr.2100-drop.fits', figure=fig, subplot=[0.5,0.1,0.35,0.8])
f2.set_tick_labels_font(size='x-small')
f2.set_axis_labels_font(size='small')
f2.show_grayscale()

f2.hide_yaxis_label()
f2.hide_ytick_labels()

fig.canvas.draw()
```

It gives me the error: AttributeError: 'FITSFigure' object has no attribute 'set_tick_labels_font'

Could you please help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Refer the [docs](https://aplpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/aplpy.FITSFigure.html) for FITSFigure. The  error occurs because `hide_yaxis_label` and `set_tick_labels_font` methods dont exist in FITSFigure class so you cannot use them.

Change the code as follows :

`f2.set_tick_labels_font` to `f2.tick_labels.set_font(size = 'small')`

`hide_yaxis_labels` to `axis_labels.hide_x()`

`hide_ytick_labels` to `tick_labels.hide_x()`

Please read the documents for class/package before using it in your code.

Comment: Thank you very much for you quick answer! It works but shows a new same error but for hide command: AttributeError: 'FITSFigure' object has no attribute 'hide_yaxis_labels'

Comment: Edited it, should solve the error

Comment: I will, Thank you again!

Comment: please approve the answer if it works :)